# Can Windows 10 desktop be extended onto iOS and Android?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, android, ios, extended-desktop

On Windows 7, I used [ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm) to extend my windows desktop from my desktop PC onto my laptop and [Air Display](https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/) to extend my desktop on my iPad and Android phone. It worked great! 4 displays made for a productive programming environment. But since upgrading to Windows 10, I've been struggling to find a way to make this work again.

I've found a replacement for ZoneScreen with [spacedesk](http://spacedesk.ph/); the current free BETA works to extend my windows desktop onto my laptop and is licensed til Dec 2016.

However, I've not had much success with extending Windows 10 desktop to Android or iOS.

After upgrading to Windows 10, I discovered [Air Display](https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/) doesn't work on Windows 10. While it detects and connects to my iPad and Android phone, the extended screen is blank.

I remembered I had previously bought [iDisplay](http://www.getidisplay.com) for [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen), so I installed it the latest version from the Play Store (3.0.1 published in Aug 2013) and I tried installed with the latest verion of the host software (iDisplay Desktop 2.5.0.12 Windows 8 Beta) on Windows 10. When I started the Android app, the Windows host software detected it, but the display driver crashed and my monitor just flickered while the app said "Connecting...".

[DuetDisplay](http://www.duetdisplay.com/) looks like a potential solution for iOS, but I don't want to buy it to find it doesn't work on Windows 10 either, and even then I'd rather find a solution that works on both iOS and Android.

It says on the [spacedesk download page](http://spacedesk.ph/download/) that they plan to release an app for Android and iOS in Q4 2015, but I wondered if anyone has experience of a working solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I settled on [spacedesk](http://spacedesk.ph/) as a solution. I used its client software to extend my Windows 10 PC on my Windows 10 laptop, and its [basic browser view](http://spacedesk.ph/basicview) worked to extend onto my iPad and Android tablet. 
And (at least currently) it's free!

Answer (score 2):

[DuetDisplay](http://www.duetdisplay.com/) works great on Windows 10. Didn't initially but in the help on their site you will find the fix you need. Highly recommend the program.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you included the fix ...

Comment: It doesn't? It appears to provide a software tool for mirroring a Windows 10 display onto an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the wireless project feature, works to all my galaxy phones to extend

https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00088544/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).